# Rails 4 with Postgres hstore, can you query keys with wildcards?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I want to be able to query keys in hstore with wildcards.

For example, I have a preferences model that has an hstore column called 'skills'.

An example of skills might be

```
{'Ruby' => {'checked' => true } }
```

Now I want to query this like so

```
Preference.where("skills LIKE :key", key: "%ruby%")

{"Angular.js"=>"{\"checked\"=>true}"}

SELECT user_id FROM preferences WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM skeys(skills) AS k WHERE k LIKE '%angular%');                                                                                    
user_id                                                                                              
---------                                                                                             
(0 rows)
```

However,

```
SELECT user_id FROM preferences WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM skeys(skills) AS k WHERE k LIKE '%a%');                                                                                    
user_id                                                                                              
---------
        1                                                                                            
(1 row)
```

Comment: What happens if you try it? What SQL does Rails generate? I would expect this to work reasonably on the SQL side (`col->key LIKE '%pattern%'`), but I don't speak ActiveRecord, so it's hard to translate reliably.

Comment: I can't seem to determine a query that would do that. Can you give me a typed out example of what you think the syntax might look like per the example above?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. You want a wildcard match on key names. That's also possible, but uglier. `CREATE TABLE some_hstore(blah hstore); INSERT INTO some_hstore(blah) VALUES ('aa=>1, ab=>2'), ('xc=>1, xd=>2'); SELECT * FROM some_hstore WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM skeys(blah) AS k WHERE k LIKE 'a%');` . In other words, a subquery `EXISTS` test of the `LIKE` expression against every key name from `skeys(the_hstore)`. That'll be "fun" in ActiveRecord ;-)

Comment: Oh, and needless to say you won't be able to use any indexes for that and performance is likely to be very bad compared to normal hstore key lookups and `?` tests. In theory you could implement a `~?` operator or something that had a `key LIKE prefix%` effect; that *could* be made indexable. It'd be a lot of work and would only work for prefix searches, not infix searches like `%pattern%`, though. This might be an indication that you need to split your `hstore` fields out into a sub-table instead.

Comment: @CraigRinger can you look at my edit, I'm getting weird wildcard issues

Comment: Also, not too worried about speed, whatever is doing these queries will be asynchronous

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you're trying to say with your edits. Can you brew up a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with sample table and data to clarify?

Comment: I think I'm going to go a different route with the way I'm storing data, at this point this seems overly complicated, but I appreciate the help. However, I will leave an answer to what I think you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per what Craig was saying in the comments, this is possible, but not efficient, here is an example query:

```
SELECT * FROM some_hstore WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM skeys(blah) AS k WHERE k ~* 'a%');
```

You can see matching patterns here from postgres http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html